# Integration test fails - getting 200 status code instead of 201 (Spring Boot, Java, Junit, Mockito)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing, junit5

I'm trying to test my **Controller** (with Junit and Mockito) in Java, but I'm not exactly sure what's going on and I need some help because Im getting stuck for quite some time right now.

**The problem:**
My test fails because **I'm expecting 201 status code** (which I'm also correctly getting when using this endpoint in postman) but the MockMvc response **returns 200 status code.**

So here is the **Controller** I'm trying to test:

```
package com.example.redditclone.posts.controllers;

import com.example.redditclone.dtos.*;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.models.Post;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.repositories.PostRepository;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.services.PostService;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.services.PostValidator;
import com.example.redditclone.users.models.User;
import com.example.redditclone.users.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {
    private PostValidator postValidator;
    private PostService postService;
    private PostRepository postRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public PostController(PostValidator postValidator, PostService postService, PostRepository postRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.postValidator = postValidator;
        this.postService = postService;
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("get")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Post>> getAllPosts() {
        List<Post> storedPosts = postRepository.findAll();
        storedPosts.sort(Comparator.comparing(Post::getReputation, Collections.reverseOrder()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(storedPosts);
    }

    @PostMapping("add")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> post(@RequestBody PostDto postDto) {
        User owner = userRepository.getReferenceById(postDto.getUserId());

        Post newPost = new Post(
                postDto.getTitle(),
                postDto.getContent(),
                owner.getUsername());
        try {
            postValidator.postThePost(newPost);
        } catch (ResponseStatusException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode()).body(new ErrorResponseDto(e.getReason()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new OkResponseDto(201, "Post was successfully added"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    // other endpoints
}
```

Here is **PostValidator** used in Controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Service
public class PostValidatorImp implements PostValidator{

    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PostValidatorImp(PostRepository postRepository) {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateTitle(Post post) {
        if (post.getTitle().length() < 8) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "The title must be at least 8 characters long");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateContent(Post post) {
        if (post.getContent().length() < 8) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "The content must be at least 8 characters long");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean postThePost(Post post) {
        boolean isTitleValid = validateTitle(post);
        boolean isContentValid = validateContent(post);
        if (isTitleValid && isContentValid) {
            Post newPost = new Post(post.getTitle(), post.getContent(), post.getOwner());
            postRepository.save(newPost);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unknown error");
        }
    }

    //other methods
}
```

This is the **test file**:

```
package com.example.redditclone.posts.controllers;

import com.example.redditclone.dtos.PostDto;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.repositories.PostRepository;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.services.PostService;
import com.example.redditclone.posts.services.PostValidator;
import com.example.redditclone.users.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;

@WebMvcTest(controllers = PostController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PostControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private PostValidator postValidator;
    @MockBean
    private PostService postService;
    @MockBean
    private PostController postController;
    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @MockBean
    private PostRepository postRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void PostController_Returns_Created_When_Adding_Post() throws Exception {
        PostDto postDto = new PostDto("This is test Title", "This is the first sentence.", 1L);

        Mockito.when(postValidator.postThePost(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("/posts/add")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(postDto))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is(201)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("Post was successfully added")));
    }
}
```

And lastly this is the **stack trace** when running the test:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /posts/add
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"81"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.redditclone.posts.controllers.PostController$MockitoMock$EnMNRmjC
           Method = com.example.redditclone.posts.controllers.PostController$MockitoMock$EnMNRmjC#post(PostDto)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<201> but was:<200>
Expected :201
Actual   :200
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<200>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:637)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:214)
    at com.example.redditclone.posts.controllers.PostControllerTest.PostController_Returns_Created_When_Adding_Post(PostControllerTest.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

Edit:
Here is the code for **OkResponseDto**:

```
package com.example.redditclone.dtos;

public class OkResponseDto extends ResponseDto{
    private Integer status;
    private String message;

    public OkResponseDto() {
    }

    public OkResponseDto(Integer status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

I have other controllers setup **the same way** and also their testing and tests are **passing** as expected. I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here so I would very much appreciate your help :)

I tried looking up for other similar topics as always but haven't found one that would help me solve my problem.

Comment: You need to post the code for OkResponseDto

Comment: Also if you call the endpoint manually is it actually returning a 201?

Comment: @possum I have edited the post and added the OkResponseDto

Comment: Yes, In postman Im getting 201 back as a response

Answer (score 0):

```
@MockBean
private PostController postController;
```

Try to `@Autowire` PostController instead of mocking it.

You're using a mocked version of PostController and then not assigning any behavior to it. The rest controller framework is going to call the mock bean's post() method which will just return null. The code in the real PostController which returns a CREATED response won't run.

Comment: Thanks! This moved me forward, but now I'm getting this error => Cannot invoke "com.example.redditclone.users.models.User.getUsername()" because "owner" is null. How do I properly mock the user in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kenster I was able to make it work. His answer was right and then I only needed to add this line of code to make it work. `Mockito.when(userRepository.getReferenceById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(user);`

Thank you, otherwise I would be still bumping my head into the wall :)